# React-router Link to маршрут дописывается в конец пути

Tags: reactjs, link, react-router

Доброго времени суток. Я новичок в js и столкнулась со следующей проблемой. Я пытаюсь сделать пагинацию, использую react-router и redux. Route '/news' и '/news/page/1' использую один и тот же компонент. У меня есть ссылки Link to, когда я перехожу по ссылкам маршрут дописывается в путь. Путь выглядит как:
http://localhost:3000/news/page/news/page/news/page/4. Как правильно реализовать такую ситуацию?

```js
export const routes = (
  <div>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      {/*}<IndexRedirect to='list' />*/}
      <Route path='/news(/page/:page)' component={News}/>    
      <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}  onEnter={Admin.onEnter}/>
      <Route path='products' component={Products}/>
      <Route path='contacts' component={Contacts}/>
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='login' component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='orders' component= {Orders}/>
      <Route path='signup' component={SignupPage}/>
      <Route path='validateEmail' component= {requireIdentification(ValidateEmail)}/>
      <Route path='/verifyEmail/:token' component={CheckEmail}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </div>
)
```

И мой упрощенный компонент News:

```js
export default class News extends Component {

  render() {
    let nextPage = + (this.props.params.page || 1);
    return(
    <div>
    <h1>I am on {nextPage}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to='news/page/2'>Page2</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='news/page/3'>Page3</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='news/page/4'>Page4</Link></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
    }}
```

Comment: Я думаю, тут речь идет о ссылках с параметрами. Почитать подробнее о чем я можно по ссылке https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте корневую ссылку:

```
<li><Link to='/news/page/2'>Page2</Link></li>
```

К слову, относительные ссылки библиотекой `react-router` и не поддерживаются. Работают они у вас, по всей видимости, случайно.